# Can't get search result while using filepath as a search field - Lucene.NET 2.9

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

My goal is to index the PATH of the files so I can search afterwards.
I have the following code:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Commit();
        writer.Close();
        String text1 = "C:\\Users\\Marto\\Desktop\\folder1\\file1.txt";
        WriteDocument(text1);
        SearchSomething("C:\\Users\\Marto\\Desktop\\folder1\\file1.txt");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void WriteDocument(String text)
    {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
        string[] DEFAULT_STOP_WORDS = { };
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29, DEFAULT_STOP_WORDS);
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        var doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("path", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));//text = "C:\\Users\\Marto\\Desktop\\folder1\\file1.txt"
        writer.AddDocument(doc);
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Commit();
        writer.Close();
    }

    private static void SearchSomething(String searchText)
    {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
        string[] DEFAULT_STOP_WORDS = { };
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29, DEFAULT_STOP_WORDS);
        var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "path", analyzer);
        Query query = parser.Parse(searchText);
        //searchText = "C:\\Users\\Marto\\Desktop\\folder1\\file1.txt"
        //but query = {C:usersmartodesktopfolder1file1.txt}
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query, 500);
        int results = topDocs.ScoreDocs.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} results", results);
        for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
        {
            ScoreDoc scoreDoc = topDocs.ScoreDocs[i];
            float score = scoreDoc.Score;
            int docId = scoreDoc.Doc;
            Document doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
            Console.WriteLine("Result num {0}, score {1}", i + 1, score);
            Console.WriteLine("Text found: {0}\r\n", doc.Get("path"));
        }
        searcher.Close();
        directory.Close();
    }

}
```

But when i search for "C:\Users\Marto\Desktop\folder1\file1.txt", the query remove the characters \ and don't return any result.

I also try with other Analyzer but I get the same result.
If any could help me, i will we very gratefull!!!

Comment: You should use KeywordAnalyzer for things like file path.

Comment: I also tried with KeywordAnalyzer but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I got it.
The solution was using `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` so that the Analyzer do not process it. And then I used a `BooleanQuery` which I added a `TermQuery` (instead of using regular `Query`) so that it does not have to parsed.

Thanks a lot for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(this.IndexPath));
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Commit();
        writer.Close();
        String text1 = "C:\\Users\\Marto\\Desktop\\folder1\\file1.txt";
        WriteDocument(text1);
        SearchSomething("C:\\Users\\Marto\\Desktop\\folder1\\file1.txt");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void WriteDocument(String text)
    {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("path", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        writer.AddDocument(doc);
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Commit();
        writer.Close();
    }

    private static void SearchSomething(String searchText)
    {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo("LuceneIndex"));
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);

        int results = 0;
        if (searcher.MaxDoc() > 0)
        {
            BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
            Lucene.Net.Search.Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("path", searchText));
            booleanQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

            TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(booleanQuery, searcher.MaxDoc());
            results = topDocs.ScoreDocs.Length;

            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} results", results);
            for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
            {
                ScoreDoc scoreDoc = topDocs.ScoreDocs[i];
                float score = scoreDoc.Score;
                int docId = scoreDoc.Doc;
                Document doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
                Console.WriteLine("Result num {0}, score {1}", i + 1, score);
                Console.WriteLine("Text found: {0}\r\n", doc.Get("path"));
            }

        }
        searcher.Close();
        directory.Close();
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the ideas!!!

Answer (score 0):

You create your "path" field as follows:

```
new Field("path", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED)
```

Your last argument (`Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`) tells Lucene not to index this field. Lucene is index-based search engine, so not indexed means not searchable. To fix it just change this argument to `Field.Index.ANALYZED`:

```
new Field("path", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)
```

Comment: thats wrong, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED is still indexed, but it is not Analyzed, which is different. From the doc: "Index the field's value without using an Analyzer, so it can be searched. As no analyzer is used the value will be stored as a single term. This is useful for unique Ids like product numbers. "

Answer (score 0):

That is because you specified `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` at index time, but you are using an Analyzer at search time.

In lucene you need to always search using the same method you indexed the data. When you create your QueryParser, use a KeywordAnalyzer and not a StandardAnalyzer, or change your field to `Field.Index.ANALYZED` at index time.